# I can bevel, but its hidden inside the cube

Tags: bevel

when i bevel the edge of the cube, it's hidden inside of the cube and i don't know why. the structure still remains of the cube eventhough i bevel it.
So i've already did face orientation. So the cube is not inside out. And I already did crtl a scale.
The bevel is hidden inside the cube. I don't know why. Look at picture. enter image description here

[image]
[image]

Comment: You must have some duplicate geometry.  A to select all and Alt + M -> Merge By Distance

Comment: Thank you so much!